# Extract part of folder name (within a folder) and get max from it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So folder with folder names that contain 2 sequence numbers. I would like to get all the folder name and select the max HF

```
R100_20170501_HF300_check1234

R200_20170621_HF122_TEST1234

R200_20170622_HF123_DF_25439

R300_20170622_HF99_DF_25439
```

Basically I want the MAX HFXXX_  between HF and underscore - in this case return 300.

Comment: Get a substring, do a numeric (or even lexicographic) comparison. Good luck.

Comment: This is not a question but a code/script request, which is off-topic here! Please do your own research and share your efforts! Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse out the number after "_HF" and find the maximum.

```
C:>DIR /B /A:D
R100_20170501_HF300_check1234
R200_20170621_HF122_TEST1234
R200_20170622_HF123_DF_25439
R300_20170622_HF99_DF_25439

C:>TYPE h.ps1
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "*_HF*_*" |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '.*_HF([0-9]*)_.*' } |
    ForEach-Object { "$($matches[1])" } |
    Measure-Object -Maximum |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Maximum }

C:>powershell -NoProfile -File h.ps1
300
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max=0
for /f "delims=_F tokens=4" %%a in ('dir R* /b /ad') do if %%a gtr !max! set max=%%a
dir /b /ad *_HF%max%_*
```

This script checks all folders and keeps the one with the greatest number in the place after the first three underscores or Fs. This means it will not reliably work if there is a chance of an F in the filename before HF.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to include this to cover future readers prefering a non powershell solution.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%A IN ("*_HF*_*") DO CALL :SUB "%%A"
ECHO [%MAX%]
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF

:SUB
SET "$=%~1"
IF "%XXX%" GTR "%MAX%" SET "MAX=%XXX%"
SET/A "XXX=%$:*_HF=%" 2>NUL
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: As is it is only returning [] - will modify and give it a shot

Comment: It works exactly as written as long as you have more than one directory along side the script containing a matching `*_HF*_*` string in it's name. _I had rare access to a Windows PC and therefore actually tested it_. If you have changed anything at all from my answer, change it back and try it again or post the altered content and ask for help with it.

Comment: yeah it didnt accept server folder, updated with pushhd, but i is considering 2 digits only (if there is 99 and 100 still shows 99)

Comment: I tested the above code with the exact names you provided, the answer, `300`, as you know, has 3 characters and is returned as `%MAX%`. If you post, _by editing your original question_, the exact code you are now using with the exact directory names you are checking, then we have a better chance of fixing your issues.

Comment: FYI there was 300 from the start but it ok