# How to get the folder name with highest number in folder name?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have multiple folders with these names:

```
ABC_03_00_016_0
ABC_03_00_016_1
ABC_03_00_016_2
ABC_03_00_016_3
ABC_03_00_016_4
ABC_03_00_016_5
```

What I want to do is to retain the folder with largest number in the end of folder name, i.e. `ABC_03_00_016_5` in above case using PowerShell or batch commands.

How to get the folder with greatest number?

Comment: What is the name of the folder after folder `ABC_03_00_016_9`? Is it `ABC_03_00_016_10` or have all folders two digits at end if one of the folder has as last number more than one digit?

Comment: yes it is "ABC_03_00_016_10". and after 99 it will be "ABC_03_00_016_100" i;e 3 digit.

Comment: What have you tried on your own, where are you stuck? Have you tried searching this site? I'm sure there were already similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44762275), for example...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be done more elegant, but it's probably working as you want. I'm stripping the last digits, converting & comparing them to then determine the highest one. As you can see, order does not matter:

```
$items = 
"ABC_03_00_016_0",
"ABC_03_00_016_100",
"ABC_03_00_016_99"

[int]$highestNumberTillNow = 0
$highestitem = ""
foreach ($item in $items){
    [int]$number = $item.substring($item.LastIndexOf("_")+1,$item.length-$item.LastIndexOf("_")-1)
    if ($number -gt $highestNumberTillNow){
        $highestNumberTillNow = $number
        $highestitem = $item
    }
}
write-host $highestitem
```

Answer (score 0):

The first method can be used only if all folder names have the same length, i.e. leading zeros are used to make sure that all numbers in all folder names have same number of digits.

```
@echo off
set "LastFolder="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0ABC_03_00_016_*" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do set "LastFolder=%%I" & goto HaveFolder
echo Found no folder matching pattern ABC_03_00_016_* in "%~dp0".
exit /B

:HaveFolder
echo Last folder according to sorted folder names is: %LastFolder%
```

The task to get folder name with greatest last number is more difficult on number of digits differs on last number.

```
@echo off
set "LastFolder="
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderNumber=-1"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0ABC_03_00_016_*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=5 delims=_" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        if %%J GTR !FolderNumber! (
            set "LastFolder=%%I"
            set "FolderNumber=%%J"
        )
    )
)
endlocal & set "LastFolder=%LastFolder%"

if not defined LastFolder (
    echo Found no folder matching pattern ABC_03_00_016_* in "%~dp0".
) else (
    echo Last folder according to last number in name is: %LastFolder%
)
```

**Note:** The last number in folder name should have never leading zeros on using the second code above. A number with one or more leading `0` is interpreted as octal number which means `08`, `09`, `18`, `19`, etc. are invalid octal numbers and are interpreted for that reason with value `0` by command **IF** on making the integer comparison. There would be additional code necessary above the **IF** condition to first remove all leading `0` from number string before doing the integer comparison.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` (drive and path of batch file ending with a backslash).
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
pushd "%~dp0"
for /f "tokens=4 delims=_" %%a in ('dir ABC_03_016_* /ad /b') do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%b in ('dir ABC_03_016_* /ad /b') do (
    set dir[%%a]=%%b
  )
)
set dc=0
:loop
set /a dc=dc+1
if defined dir[%dc%] goto loop
goto break
:break
set /a dc=dc-1
echo The folder is !dir[%dc%]!
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you **could** have more folders with a similar name in the root path like

> ```
> ABC_03_00_016_0
> ABC_03_00_016_1
> ABC_03_00_016_2
> ABC_03_00_016_3
> ABC_03_00_016_4
> ABC_03_00_016_5
> DEF_03_00_016_0
> DEF_03_00_016_1
> DEF_03_00_016_10
> ```

Using PowerShell you can use something like below.
This will return the folder object(s) with the highest number at the end of the name:

```
$lastFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\test' -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '(.+)_(\d+)$' } |
    Group-Object -Property @{Expression={ $matches[1] }}  | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={ [int]$matches[2] }} | Select-Object -Last 1
    }

# for demo, just output the FullName property of the folders found
$lastFolder.FullName
```

Output:

> ```
> D:\test\ABC_03_00_016_5
> D:\test\DEF_03_00_016_10
> ```

Regex details:

```
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .         Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
_            Match the character “_” literally
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
$            Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to remove all of the directories except for the one ending with the largest number, then I'd suggest PowerShell too:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Naqqash\Desktop' -Filter '*_*_*_*_*' -Directory |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -Match '(.+)_(\d+)$' } |
    Sort-Object -Property { [Int]$($_.Name).Split('_')[-1] } |
      Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |
        Remove-Item
```

Please remember to adjust the path on line 1 to that holding your directories.

*The example above requires PowerShell v5.0*